# If Statement depending on the Category a Product belongs to (Big Cartel)

Tags: bigcartel

Can I create an if statement on the *Product.html* page depending on the category which a product belongs to? Something like this:

```
{% if product.category.name == 'Shirts' %}
     <div>Some Content</div>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a product can be listed in multiple categories, you'll need to use a `for` loop to go through all the categories, and then include an `if` statement to check the name - like so:

```
{% for category in product.categories %}
  {% if category.name == 'Shirts' %}
    <div>Your content</div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```